# Directory Entry passed in credentials not being used for commit changes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory

I am creating a web application that connects to Active Directory and allows users to edit their own details in Active Directory from the app.

Users can see other users details so the app uses windows authentication to only allow editing of a user's own details. Obviously I can't provide every user Admin privileges to allow this so upon setting up the Directory Entry I pass it the credentials for an admin service account.

Upon reaching commit changes I can see that the ADEntry credentials are correct. However, it appears to not be using the passed in credentials and instead uses the windows authentication credentials.

When an admin user runs the app they can change details but when a non-admin user runs the app they get error - Access is denied - upon reaching CommitChanges(). This leads me to believe it is using the windows authentication credentials rather than those supplied in DirectoryEntry(credentials)

Any ideas? 
Do I need to use Impersonation?

```
DirectoryEntry ADEntry()
{
    using (DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername, myAdminServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))

        {
            return ADEntry;
        }
}

DirectorySearcher ADSearcher()
{
    using(DirectorySearcher ADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(ADEntry()))
    {
        return ADSearcher;
    }
}

SearchResult GetADSearchResult(string userToFind)
{
    SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult();
    DirectorySearcher ADS = ADSearcher();
    ADS.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" + userToFind + "))";
    searchResult = ADS.FindOne();
    return searchResult;
}

void SetProperty(string userToFind, string propertyToChange, string newPropertyValue)
{
    SearchResult searchResult = GetADSearchResult(userToFind);
    DirectoryEntry _ADEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if (_ADEntry.Properties.Contains(propertyToChange))
    {  
        _ADEntry.Properties[propertyToChange].Remove(_ADEntry.Properties[propertyToChange].Value);
    }
    _ADEntry.Properties[propertyToChange].Insert(0, newPropertyValue);
    _ADEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: You show `ADEntry` being created and returned from within a `using` block. The `using` block will dispose the `ADEntry` on the way out of that scope. I think the code sample is a bit confusing. Could you clean it up a bit to better show the order of operations?

Comment: Apologies I only had copied code snippets at the time, that should make more sense now. The error happens at _ADEntry.CommitChanges() when calling SetProperty but only when logged into the windows authentication as a non-admin

Comment: Hrm... still a little confused about the first two "methods", `ADEntry` and `ADSearcher`. Are these supposed to be methods or are they supposed to represent a class/constructor? The `GetADSearchResult` method is `new`-ing them up. Asking because this still doesn't clear up my concern that you're using an instance after it has been disposed by the `using` block.

Comment: That's what I get for trying to code in notepad since I don't have access to my workstation at the moment. They are methods the 'new' in GetADSearchResult was a typo, edited out. The using block shouldn't be causing issues as when I break within SetProperty, _ADEntry has the correct myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername and myAdminServicePassword that are set within ADEntry(). I am also able to retrieve details from active directory using those same methods.

Comment: In other words the Directory Entry created in ADEntry() and Searcher in ADSearcher() are accessible, displaying the correct information, from other methods

Comment: From the docs: "The Dispose method leaves the Component in an unusable state." Unfortunately, I can't comment on the implementation details of `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`. But, why do you think it's OK to use the objects after they've been disposed? Have you tested these methods without first disposing the objects?

Comment: My understanding is if _ADEntry = ADEntry(). Therefore the entry created within the ADEntry method is disposed. However, _ADEntry is set before disposing ADEntry. _ADEntry is never disposed and therefore keeps the data. I haven't tried it without the using clause though

Comment: When you `new DirectorySearcher(...)` inside `ADSearcher`, the `DirectoryEntry` you pass has already been disposed. That's the concern I was raising. I was not trying to imply that `_ADEntry` is ever disposed. Hope that's clearer!

Comment: I will definitely test without the `using` see if it makes a difference but a `DirectoryEntry` isn't passed into `ADSearcher` the `ADEntry` method is called creating a new `DirectoryEntry`. Are you suggesting it should perhaps be `DirectoryEntry newEntry = ADEntry(); DirectorySearcher ADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(newEntry)`?

Comment: According to your current code example, a `DirectoryEntry` _is_ being passed to the `DirectorySearcher`. It's one created (and disposed) by the `ADEntry` method. I'll post an answer (that unfortunately won't actually answer your question) with example code highlighting the issue.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but I know that the `ADEntry` and `ADSearcher` are working as expected because due to `SetProperty` working correctly when logged in as an admin account. My understanding is that this is because they are being passed and then disposed, if they were disposed and then passed wouldn't it return `null` and therefore other errors? I will test tomorrow without the `using`s though and see if their is any difference. Thank you for your time, this is my first time posting here and will definitely try improve initial formatting in the future

Comment: No, it's not necessarily the case that they would return `null` after being disposed. This is where it becomes very implementation dependent (and why I commented I'm not familiar with their specific implementation). Object methods _may_ still work after being disposed. That entirely depends on the method implementations. But `IDisposable` represents a _contract_ and, once an object has been disposed, you _shouldn't_ be using it anymore. Like the docs say: "The Dispose method leaves the Component in an unusable state."

Comment: That's interesting, so it could be keeping the data but not the credentials after being disposed, in theory. Worth a try, thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

These methods are creating, immediately disposing, and then returning some object instances:

```cs
DirectoryEntry ADEntry()
{
    using (DirectoryEntry ADEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername, myAdminServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
    {
        return ADEntry;
    }
}

DirectorySearcher ADSearcher()
{
    using(DirectorySearcher ADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(ADEntry()))
    {
        return ADSearcher;
    }
}
```

So this:

```cs
...
DirectorySearcher ADS = ADSearcher();
ADS.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" + userToFind + "))";
searchResult = ADS.FindOne();
...
```

...can effectively be translated to this:

```cs
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername, myAdminServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
directoryEntry.Dispose();

var directorySearcher = = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.Dispose();

directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" + userToFind + "))";
var searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();
```

Unfortunately, I don't have an AD available to test against, and it's possible that this isn't the root cause of your issue. However, I would recommend fixing the code to not use object instances after they have been disposed. The following might be a better approach:

```cs
SearchResult searchResult;
using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername, myAdminServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
using (var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry))
{
    directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" + userToFind + "))";
    searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();
}

// It's OK to use searchResult here, it's not `IDisposable`.
```

Comment: Wouldn't the translation be `var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(myDomain, myAdminServiceUsername, myAdminServicePassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure); var de = directoryEntry;
directoryEntry.Dispose();` Although even then I'm still not sure if it's worth using `using`

Comment: `var directorySearcher = = new DirectorySearcher(de); ds = directorySearcher;
directorySearcher.Dispose(); ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" + userToFind + "))";
var searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();`

Comment: Not sure if it'll change the error but it's worth a try, this is the only suggestion I've found from searching throughout the day so it's worth a shot

Comment: @KieranJack No, that doesn't make it any different. Both `directoryEntry` and your `de` are references pointing to the same object instance. The one instance is still being disposed. Assigning the object to another variable _does not_ perform any kind of object copy!

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, my understanding of `Dispose` was wrong, it's the object in memory not the variable pointing to the object

Comment: In my experience, there isn't usually any value in disposing `DirectoryEntry` or `DirectorySearcher` objects. An exception is if you're looping over thousands of accounts; the garbage collector doesn't have time to catch up, so disposing the objects helps keep memory consumption down. Also, always dispose [`SearchResultCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection) when using [`DirectorySearcher.FindAll()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall) (see the 'Remarks' section)